# Unable to find table after successfully connecting to database file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm currently a console application tool using C# where user is allowed to input the directory of the database file (which is located somewhere on the desktop), and I am required to get the .db file from the specified location and connect it followed by retrieving it's content from the table into a text file. However I'm getting a SQLite error stating that the table is not found. And whenever I run the code, It creates a copy of the .db file but its empty.

But this error doesn't show when I manually 'copy-paste' a copy of the .db file in my debug folder. So I'm wondering is it a must to keep a copy in the debug folder or is there any other way to allow something like a remote connection. (FYI. I'm really new to C# and SQLite).

```
connectionString = "DataSource=myDataBase.db";
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT File,Path FROM Structure", connection))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Do some stuffs
            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: The DataSource='the .db file name'

Comment: Don't describe it, *show* it!

Comment: connectionString = "DataSource=myDataBase.db";

Comment: You are able open the connection? What error you are getting?

Comment: As @CL. said I didn't include path of the file in the DataSource which causes the SQLite to create an empty .db file in my current directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a file path, the database file will be searched for in the current directory (whatever it happens to be).

When the database file does not exist, SQLite will happily create a new, empty one.

Include the complete directory in the connection string:

```
connectionString = "DataSource=C:\\some\\where\\myDataBase.db";
```